# Why and how do some servers implement TLS framing that split server response body in a few small frames?

Tags: http, ssl, networking, server, http2

While investigating my network activities and MiTM I noticed that some SSL over HTTP2.0 responses are sent to my machine in a few separate "Application Data" frames with lengths e.g. 149 bytes -> 728 -> 520 -> 33.

Can anyone advise me the reason and/or examples of this server configuration?

Comment: why are you asking the same question twice ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43651323/why-do-i-receive-http-response-in-a-multiple-small-packets

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I receive HTTP response in a multiple small packets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43651323/why-do-i-receive-http-response-in-a-multiple-small-packets)

Comment: Just making it more clear to get an answer.